# Mongoose relations design

Tags: node.js, mongodb, relationships, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I've recently started using Mongoose with Express.js in a Node.js application and I have a question about a proper way to design my schemas.

I have several schemas that have some relationships, i.e. Location schema has an array of Objects (it's not a JS object in this context), and Object schema has its Location property. I've learned that relationships in Mongoose are resolved using population, but when I implemented this approach I noticed that I have to type a lot of duplicate code, i.e. whenever I want to create a new Object I have to also update the Location's array of Objects and then assign the Location to the Object's property. Wouldn't it be more trivial to just manually assemble all the Objects that has a locationId property equal to the Location that I want to get from the database in a separate query?

I have also considered just storing Objects in an array in a Location document (as subdocuments) but I decided that I want to be able to work with Objects (create, remove, update) separately from Locations (without querying a Location) so this approach doesn't fit my needs I guess. But then population has its drawbacks too in my case, so I guess it's really the best to just go with manually collecting Objects of a specific Location in a separate query by that Location's id.

I would like to hear an opinion of some professional or advanced user of this technology on designing Mongoose schemas so that I and others don't get into trouble later maintaining and scaling our applications.

Here are my current schemas in question:

```
var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    objects: [{ type: String, ref: 'object' }]
});

var objectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    location: { type: String, ref: 'location' }
});
```

Comment: can You put in question all schemas You've?

Comment: I've just done that. :)

Comment: For those of you who are interested, I've just tried using `mongoose-autopopulate` with both of my schemas and ended up with an out of memory error. I believe this happened because of a circular reference: I've requested a Location that has one Object, so that Location was autopopulated with that Object, then that Object automatically requested its Location, then that Location requested its Object again and this loop continued until OOM error. So those of you who has some circural references in your schemas (and I believe this is frequently the case) - don't try using `mongoose-autopopulate`.

Comment: because You're doing cross-relation in Your schemas and autopopulate walks through circular references and it gets out of memory (:

Comment: Yeah, I've just explained that myself. :)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this example

db/schemas.js:

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ObjectSchema = {
    title: Schema.Types.String
}

const LocationSchema = new Schema({
    title: Schema.Types.String,
    objects: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Object'}]
})

module.exports = {
  Object: ObjectSchema,
  Location: LocationSchema
};
```

db/model.js:

```
const 
 mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 schemas = require('./schemas');

module.exports = model => mongoose.model(model, schemas[model+'Schema']);
```

usage:

```
const 
  model = require('./db/model'),
  LocationModel = model('Location');

LocationModel
  .findOne({_id: 'some id here'})
  .populate('objects')
  .exec((err, LocationInstance) => {
    console.log(LocationInstance.title, ' objects:', LocationInstance.objects); 
  });
```

when You create an object and want to relate to location:

```
const 
  model = require('./db/model'),
  ObjectModel = model('Object'),
  LocationModel = model('Location');

let 
  ObjectInstance = new ObjectModel({title: 'Something'});
  ObjectInstance.save((err, result) => {
    LocationModel
      .findByIdAndUpdate(
        'some id here', 
        {$push: {objects: ObjectInstance._id}},
        (err) => {
          console.log('Object:', ObjectInstance.title, ' added to location');
        });
  });
```

updating object data:

```
  const 
    model = require('./db/model'),
    ObjectModel = model('Object');

  let id = 'id of object';

  ObjectModel
    .findByIdAndUpdate(
      id, 
      {title: 'Something #2'},
      (err) => {
        console.log('Object title updated');
      });
```

finding location by object:

```
  const 
    model = require('./db/model'),
    LocationModel = model('Object');

  let id = 'id of object';

  LocationModel
    .findOne({objects: id})
    .populate('objects')
    .exec((err, LocationInstance) => {
      console.log('Location objects:', LocationInstance.objects);
    });
```

nothing special `findOne({objects: id})` will search inside location documents that has relation by id in objects array

any other question welcome (:

Comment: Thank you so much for such a comprehensive post. However, you've just showed a way how to implement relations using Mongoose population, which I have already done the exact same way (I've mentioned in my question that population is the problem that I'm looking a solution for). My exact question was to explain why something is better than something else.

Comment: @Salivan there is no pros-cons, just use the way that You prefer, that is comfortable to You and make sure Your code is easy to read. NodeJS is very versatile technology. It's hard to find 2 devs that will do task same way.

Comment: @Salivan if You look for best practices using expressjs I recommend You to take a look at this: https://www.terlici.com/2014/08/25/best-practices-express-structure.html

Comment: Well, I always wanted to accomplish things in a way that is acceptable and tested to be good. If there really isn't anything that is much better than populations, I guess I'll keep using them, or if I find it trully an overhead, I'll just switch to separate queries to get related objects by id.

Comment: P.S. I would really like to mark your answer as accepted because of the effort you've made, but I don't think that would be rational, because it doesn't really answer my question. :(

Comment: @Salivan, no need to mark as accepted. It's ok. Maybe somebody will respond with good idea. Actually in world of nodejs it's better not to complicate too much. If You wanna see an example of how I structurize my apps: https://bitbucket.org/num8er/citymag-az-website little bit developed version of best practices documentation.

Comment: Thank you for resources!